# Data structure which is efficient to add new number and count how many stored numbers smaller than some query number

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I want to find an efficient data structure that can handle the following use case.

I can add new elements to this data structure, e.g.
I call `add()` API, `add([2,3,4,5,3])`, then this data structure stores `[2,3,3,4,5]`. I can `query` some `target` and return how many numbers smaller than this target. e.g. `query(4)`, return `3` (since one `2` and two `3`). And the frequencies of calling `add` and `query` are in the same order.

Firstly, I think of `segment tree`, however, the input number can be anyone in `int` value, space will be `O(2^32)`

Could you give me some advice about which data structure should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), which is a kind of binary search tree where each node also stores the cardinality of its own subtree. Inserting into an order statistic tree still takes O(log *n*) time, because it's a binary search tree, although the insert operation is a little more complicated because it has to keep the cardinalities of each node up-to-date.

Computing the number of members less than a given target also takes O(log *n*) time; start at the root node:

- If the target is less than or equal to the root node's value, then recurse on the left subtree.
- Otherwise, return the left child's cardinality plus the result of recursing on the right subtree.

The base case is that you always return 0 for an empty subtree.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much.